# Flask Admin field doesnt populate on create_form

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a flask-sqlalchemy model and I want to pre-populate the `id` field with a default entry when creating a new entry.

I tried the following but it doesnt seem to work.

```py
class Readergroup(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'readergroups'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    readers = db.relationship('Reader', secondary=readergroup_readers,  lazy='subquery')


class ReadergroupView(MyModelView):
    form_columns = ['id', 'name', 'readers']
    column_list = ['id', 'name', 'readers']
    column_labels = dict(id='id')
    column_searchable_list = ['id', 'name', 'readers.name']

 def create_form(self):
    form = super(MyModelView, self).create_form()
    form.id = 1
    return form
```

The form loads with `id` field empty.

I also tried to use `get_create_form(self)` instead but it also didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form.id` is the form's field for the `id` column, `form.id.data` holds the field's value.

```
def create_form(self):
    form = super(MyModelView, self).create_form()
    form.id.data = 1
    return form
```